# structured type array initializing

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have structure and I have this structured type array, i am trying to initialize array element using for but string array is the same

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string.h"

#define NUMBER_OF_STARS         200
#define NUMBER_OF_PLANETS       200

//== STAR STRUCTURE ==//
// NAME | DIAMTER | TEMPERATURE | COMPANION PLANET/S  //
//== END STRUCTURE ==//
typedef struct _star
{
    char *name;
    int diameter;
    int temperature;

}star;
//== STAR STRUCTURE ==//
// NAME | DISTANCE TO STAR | TWIRLING STAR | SPEED IN SPACE  //
//== END STRUCTURE ==//
typedef struct _planet
{
    char *name;
    int distance_to_star;
    char *twirling_star;
    int speed_in_space;
}planet;
typedef struct _galaxy
{
    star   s_star;
    planet s_planet;
}galaxy;

int main()
{
    star s_star[NUMBER_OF_STARS];
    printf("Create your STARS\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter name of STAR\n");
        char s_name[20];
        scanf_s(" %s", s_name, 20);
        printf("Enter diameter of STAR\n");
        int s_diameter;
        scanf_s(" %i", &s_diameter);
        printf("Enter temperature of STAR\n");
        int s_temperature;
        scanf_s("%i", &s_temperature);
        char s_com_planet[20];
        printf("\n");
        s_star[i] = { s_name,s_diameter,s_temperature };
        printf("Would you want to create another one?(YES/NO)\n");
        char cmd_answer[5];
        scanf_s("%s", cmd_answer, 5);
        if (strstr(cmd_answer, "YES")) continue;
        else if(strstr(cmd_answer, "NO")) break;
        else break;
        //printf("Name of STAR:\t\t%s\nDiameter of STAR:\t%i\nTemperature of STAR:\t%i\n\n", s_star->name, s_star->diameter, s_star->temperature);
    }

    printf("%s", s_star[1].name);

    for (;;);
    return 0;
}
```

and when I entered for example:

```
 name1 
 1
 1
```

than again

```
name2
2
2
```

then again

```
name3
3
3
```

visual studio show that in the `s_star` array `s_star[0].name` `s_star[1].name` `s_star[2].name` is the same in my case output is `name3`
can anyone figure out this and explain me, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: For each char* struct member, you're reading into one automatic (on-the-stack) array and setting the char* member to point to it.  You can fix the problem by saving pointers to malloc'd memory instead.

Answer (score 0):

`star` contains pointers. You can initialize the array to zero as follows:

```
star s_star[NUMBER_OF_STARS] = { 0 };
```

If `star` did not contain pointers, you could initialize during declaration:

```
star s = { 0,123,456 };
//or
star array[] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };
```

But in this case you have to set the members manually:

```
//(in this case is not necessary to check the previous value)
if (s_star[i].name) 
    free(s_star[i].name);

s_star[i].name = malloc(strlen(s_name) + 1);
strcpy_s(s_star[i].name, (strlen(s_name) + 1), s_name);

s_star[i].diameter = s_diameter;
s_star[i].temperature = s_temperature;
```

Not related to your question, but in Visual Studio use `system("pause")` instead of `for(;;);` to pause the program in debug mode.

Comment: In C99 and later, you could use a 'compound literal' to do the assignment in one go.  There'd still be a need to copy the strings, though (which could be done with `strdup()`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't know what you mean. `s_star[i] = { s_name,s_diameter,s_temperature };` or `s_star[i] = {0,0,0};` does not even compile in Visual Studio, I don't know how OP got it working. I couldn't compile that in gcc either. Maybe you can add another answer.

Comment: That's not a compound literal — but this is:  `s_star[i] = (star){ s_name, s_diameter, s_temperature };`.  The 'cast' is a key component of the construction.  Compound literals are a feature of C99 which may not be available in MSVS even yet, but they're available in GCC all right.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I see. That works in Visual Studio 2015 too.

Comment: Good; MSVS 2015 seems have done quite a lot of catching up with C99 (and perhaps with C11 too).  IIRC, the behaviour of `snprintf()` was fixed, too, so it behaves like C99.